# Is it necessary to donate to be able to download vlc media player for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: vlc, downloads

I am unable to download vlc media player.  I use Ubuntu 14.04.  Is it because I haven't made a donation yet?

Comment: Give more details about what you have done and what error is rising? There must be another issue.

Answer (score 2):

No, VLC is free.You can download it without any fee.